# Remove the "-" negative sign from currency on Formula Text Field

Tags: formula

I have a formula text field contains three fields.  One a currency field, a % field, and a date field.
The % and Data field are fine.  The issue is with the Currency field.  I have been able to add in the "$" sign and comma - leaving out the decimals.
But I need to include the parathesis for negatives and not a "-" negative sign.  How can I do this without "re-creating" my formula????
FYI - It has to be a formula text field....

```
 IF(Amount__c < 0, "(","") & "$" & 
    CASE(LEN(TEXT(Amount__c)), 
    1, TEXT(Amount__c), 
    2, TEXT(Amount__c), 
    3, TEXT(Amount__c), 
    4, LEFT(TEXT(Amount__c), 1) & "," & RIGHT(TEXT(Amount__c), 3), 
    5, LEFT(TEXT(Amount__c), 2) & "," & RIGHT(TEXT(Amount__c), 3), 
    6, LEFT(TEXT(Amount__c), 3) & "," & RIGHT(TEXT(Amount__c), 3), 
    7, LEFT(TEXT(Amount__c), 1) & "," & MID(TEXT(Amount__c), 2,3) & "," & RIGHT(TEXT(Amount__c), 3), 
    8, LEFT(TEXT(Amount__c), 2) & "," & MID(TEXT(Amount__c), 3,3) & "," & RIGHT(TEXT(Amount__c), 3), 
    9, LEFT(TEXT(Amount__c), 3) & "," & MID(TEXT(Amount__c), 4,3) & "," & RIGHT(TEXT(Amount__c), 3), 
    10, LEFT(TEXT(Amount__c), 1) & "," & MID(TEXT(Amount__c), 2,3) & "," & MID(TEXT(Amount__c), 5,3) & "," & RIGHT(TEXT(Amount__c), 3), 
    11, LEFT(TEXT(Amount__c), 2) & "," & MID(TEXT(Amount__c), 3,3) & "," & MID(TEXT(Amount__c), 6,3) & "," & RIGHT(TEXT(Amount__c), 3), 
    12, LEFT(TEXT(Amount__c), 3) & "," & MID(TEXT(Amount__c), 4,3) & "," & MID(TEXT(Amount__c), 7,3) & "," & RIGHT(TEXT(Amount__c), 3), null) & 
    IF(Amount__c < 0, ")","") &
```

Updated with the ABS(

```
SUBSTITUTE (
IF(Amount__c < 0, "(","") & "$" &
CASE(LEN(TEXT(ABS(Amount__c))),
1, TEXT(ABS(Amount__c)),
2, TEXT(ABS(Amount__c)),
3, TEXT(ABS(Amount__c)),
4, LEFT(TEXT(ABS(Amount__c)), 1) & "," & RIGHT(TEXT(ABS(Amount__c)), 3),
5, LEFT(TEXT(ABS(Amount__c)), 2) & "," & RIGHT(TEXT(ABS(Amount__c)), 3),
6, LEFT(TEXT(ABS(Amount__c)), 3)) & "," & RIGHT(TEXT(ABS(Amount__c)), 3),
7, LEFT(TEXT(ABS(Amount__c)), 1) & "," & MID(TEXT(ABS(Amount__c)), 2,3) & "," & RIGHT(TEXT(ABS(Amount__c)), 3),
8, LEFT(TEXT(ABS(Amount__c)), 2) & "," & MID(TEXT(ABS(Amount__c)), 3,3) & "," & RIGHT(TEXT(ABS(Amount__c)), 3),
9, LEFT(TEXT(ABS(Amount__c)), 3) & "," & MID(TEXT(ABS(Amount__c)), 4,3) & "," & RIGHT(TEXT(ABS(Amount__c)), 3),
10, LEFT(TEXT(ABS(Amount__c)), 1) & "," & MID(TEXT(ABS(Amount__c)), 2,3) & "," & MID(TEXT(ABS(Amount__c)), 5,3) & "," & RIGHT(TEXT(ABS(Amount__c)), 3),
11, LEFT(TEXT(ABS(Amount__c)), 2) & "," & MID(TEXT(ABS(Amount__c)), 3,3) & "," & MID(TEXT(ABS(Amount__c)), 6,3) & "," & RIGHT(TEXT(ABS(Amount__c)), 3),
12, LEFT(TEXT(ABS(Amount__c)), 3) & "," & MID(TEXT(ABS(Amount__c)), 4,3) & "," & MID(TEXT(ABS(Amount__c)), 7,3) & "," & RIGHT(TEXT(ABS(Amount__c)), 3), null) &
IF(Amount__c < 0, ")",""),"-","")
```

Comment: What does it mean "without "re-creating" my formula??"

Comment: So do you or don't you have the () currently working. From what you posted it looks like you do. Is all you need is the - removed? Please update your question. If the () are not working state what is going on. Please don't make us guess

Comment: Hello Eric, the () are working but I would like to remove the "-" if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Substitute

```
SUBSTITUTE(
IF(Amount__c < 0, "(","") & "$" & 
    CASE(LEN(TEXT(Amount__c)), 
    1, TEXT(Amount__c), 
    2, TEXT(Amount__c), 
    3, TEXT(Amount__c), 
    4, LEFT(TEXT(Amount__c), 1) & "," & RIGHT(TEXT(Amount__c), 3), 
    5, LEFT(TEXT(Amount__c), 2) & "," & RIGHT(TEXT(Amount__c), 3), 
    6, LEFT(TEXT(Amount__c), 3) & "," & RIGHT(TEXT(Amount__c), 3), 
    7, LEFT(TEXT(Amount__c), 1) & "," & MID(TEXT(Amount__c), 2,3) & "," & RIGHT(TEXT(Amount__c), 3), 
    8, LEFT(TEXT(Amount__c), 2) & "," & MID(TEXT(Amount__c), 3,3) & "," & RIGHT(TEXT(Amount__c), 3), 
    9, LEFT(TEXT(Amount__c), 3) & "," & MID(TEXT(Amount__c), 4,3) & "," & RIGHT(TEXT(Amount__c), 3), 
    10, LEFT(TEXT(Amount__c), 1) & "," & MID(TEXT(Amount__c), 2,3) & "," & MID(TEXT(Amount__c), 5,3) & "," & RIGHT(TEXT(Amount__c), 3), 
    11, LEFT(TEXT(Amount__c), 2) & "," & MID(TEXT(Amount__c), 3,3) & "," & MID(TEXT(Amount__c), 6,3) & "," & RIGHT(TEXT(Amount__c), 3), 
    12, LEFT(TEXT(Amount__c), 3) & "," & MID(TEXT(Amount__c), 4,3) & "," & MID(TEXT(Amount__c), 7,3) & "," & RIGHT(TEXT(Amount__c), 3), null) & 
    IF(Amount__c < 0, ")","") & //You ended your formula here
, '-','')
```

> SUBSTITUTE(text, old_text, new_text) and replace text with the field
>   or value for which you want to substitute values, old_text with the
>   text you want replaced, and new_text with the text you want to replace
>   the old_text.

Comment: @ Eric, you are the man!!!!

Comment: Hey Eric, Question - when I get a negative value I am receiving a "," in front of the currency.  Example: ($,145,000) and it should be ($145,000).  Thoughts?

Comment: Try changing Using `ABS(Amount__c) in your case options.

Comment: When I add in ABS in place of the TEXT I receive errors asking to the LEN to be removed and to remove the SUBTRACT( portion as well

Comment: @AwesomeUser2 - I did not say replace the TEXT I said use ABS(Amount__c) in place of Amount__c

Comment: I added the sample up top...something like this?

Comment: Possibly. Does it work?